# Unable to copy _ from pdf

Tags: pdf, copy-paste

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,OT4]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Text with \_.
\end{document}
```

In PDF there is a correct output: `Text with _.`
But when I select and copy it I get: `Text with .`

It happens on Adobe Reader, Foxit Reader and on Sumatra PDF so I think it is not a reader issue.

How can it be fixed?

Comment: WHy do you need the two encodings (`OT4` and `T1`)?

Comment: I really don't know :P. I have always had T1 and OT4 in my docs...

Comment: I've added a remark to my answer.

Comment: @Ichibann The T1 encoding has complete coverage for Polish diacritics. There is *no* need for OT4 for typesetting Polish.

Comment: It's 2012. Go Unicode and use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and forget about encodings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
\usepackage[OT4,T1]{fontenc}
```

As far as I can see it, you don't really need the `OT4` encoding; according to this remark from the `fontenc` documentation referring to `OT4`:

> While Knuth included the means of typesetting the ‘lost L’ (Ł) in his
>   OT1 encoding, he omitted the ogonek, a diacritic mark that is
>   also needed in Polish text; hence the appearance, well before the `T1`
>   encoding, of fonts using this encoding.

So you can simply say

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Comment: I have `\usepackage[T1,OT4]{fontenc}` in my real document. I think I need `OT4`.

Comment: @Ichibann use `\usepackage[OT4,T1]{fontenc}`; by the way, you should have mentioned this in the question.

Comment: Gonzalo, I didn't know it was causing the problem. I tried to make a real MWE. So I removed everything that didn't change the output. This included `\usepackage[T1,OT4]{fontenc}`.

Answer (score 6):

"Old" fontencodings like OT1 or OT4 don't have a glyph for `\_` (`\textunderscore`), they use the default defined in the kernel which is a small rule. But you can change this default so that the glyph from the T1-encoding is used instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,OT4]{fontenc}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textunderscore}{T1}
\begin{document}
Text with \_.
\end{document}
```