# Why my contenttable lowercases chapters' names?

Tags: table-of-contents

My document looks like that:

```
% book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[
  % Replace twoside with oneside if you are printing your thesis on a single side
  % of the paper, or for viewing on screen.
  polish,
  oneside,
  %twoside,
  11pt, a4paper,
  footinclude=true,
  headinclude=true,
  cleardoublepage=empty
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Tabela}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Rys.}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT4]{fontenc}

\usepackage{polski}

\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % <-- 2 includes up to subsections in the ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % <-- 3 numbers up to subsubsections

\tableofcontents
```

When I started playing with polish language for the document suddenly content table lowercases all chapters' names. Section names are ok. Why? How to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The OT4 encoding is obsolete. Use `T1` instead.

Comment: That is it. Thank you I had much trouble with this one!

Answer (score 2):

The OT4 encoding is to be considered obsolete: the T1 encoding has complete coverage of the Polish characters (see [Unable to copy _ from pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68993/unable-to-copy-from-pdf)).

So just do

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

If I make this change to your code and add

```
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
```

I get the following output for the table of contents:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is somehow being caused by the "classicthesis" package. 
I am not familiar with it, but by commenting out everything and gradually bringing them back shows that this package is causing this (I initially suspected the polish version of babel, but no).